# cant Insert into table from query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below is my Query and it works properly, but when i execute (INSERT INTO TABLE...) i got message:

> Too few parameters Expected 2.

My Query:

```
SELECT [forms]![frmSknFctr]![cboFctrs] AS IdFctr, tblSkn.Id AS IdSkn, Val([forms]![frmSknFctr]![txtBedFctr]) AS Bed
FROM tblSkn
WHERE (((tblSkn.Mlk)=True) AND ((tblSkn.Actv)=True));
```

My Insert into Command:

```
CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO tblSknFctr (ExIdFctr, ExIdSkn, Bed) SELECT IdFctr, IdSkn, Bed FROM qryInsrtSknFctr;"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Access can be a little quirky sometimes. If this were my problem I would do this:

```
DoCmd.RunSql "INSERT INTO tblSknFctr (ExIdFctr, ExIdSkn, Bed) 
              SELECT [forms]![frmSknFctr]![cboFctrs], tblSkn.Id, Val([forms]![frmSknFctr]![txtBedFctr])
              FROM tblSkn
              WHERE (((tblSkn.Mlk)=True) AND ((tblSkn.Actv)=True));"
```

If that doesn't work, put a break on the select and make sure all columns have a value. If any are null, make sure your table allows nulls for that column. This shouldn't be too difficult to debug if you break your way through it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Queries run in DAO methods like `CurrentDb.Execute` are *backend* queries that cannot see *frontend* objects like forms or reports. Instead, consider saving your query as an Access stored query to run with a *frontend* method, `DoCmd.OpenQuery`, that can reference form/report controls.

**SQL** *(save as query object)*

```sql
INSERT INTO tblSknFctr (ExIdFctr, ExIdSkn, Bed) 
SELECT IdFctr, IdSkn, Bed 
FROM qryInsrtSknFctr
```

**VBA** *(action queries do not need to be closed)*

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedAppendQuery"
```